# Do penitent / penitence, penance, and repent / repentance share a common ancestor?

Tags: etymology

Do the following three groups of English words share a common ancestor?

- [penitent](https://www.etymonline.com/word/penitent) / [penitence](https://www.etymonline.com/word/penitence)

  > penitent (adj.)
  >
  > "sorry for offenses committed, repentant of one's sins, contrite," mid-14c., from Old French pénitent (14c.) and directly from Latin paenitentem (Medieval Latin penitentem) "penitent" (see penitence).
  >
  > As a noun, "one undergoing penance, a repentant sinner," late 14c., from the adjective (earlier in this sense was penaunt, early 14c., from Old French peneant). Also, in plural, a name distinguishing some Catholic orders, especially those formed for the reception of reformed courtesans.

  > penitence (n.)
  >
  > "sorrow for committing sin or for having offended, with the intention of amending one's life; mortification undertaken to make amends for sin," c. 1200, **from Old French penitence (11c.) and directly from Latin pænitentia "repentance"** (Medieval Latin penitentia), noun of condition from pænitentum (nominative pænitens) "penitent," present participle of pænitere "cause or feel regret," probably originally "is not enough, is unsatisfactory," from pæne "nearly, almost, practically," which is of uncertain origin. The basic meaning seems to be "missing, lacking." Related: Penitency.
- [penance](https://www.etymonline.com/word/penance)

  > penance (n.)
  >
  > c. 1300, penaunce, "religious discipline or self-mortification as a token of repentance and as atonement for some sin; sorrow for sin shown by outward acts under authority and regulation of the Church," from Anglo-French penaunce, Old French peneance (12c.), from Latin pænitentia "repentance," noun of condition from pænitentum (nominative pænitens) "penitent," present participle of pænitere "cause or feel regret," probably originally "is not enough, is unsatisfactory," from pæne "nearly, almost, practically," which is of uncertain origin. Transferred sense of "repentance, contrition" is recorded from c. 1300. A popular Old French form, later ousted by the clerical pénitence, which preserves more of the Latin word.
- [repent](https://www.etymonline.com/word/repent) / [repentance](https://www.etymonline.com/word/repentance)

  > repent (v.)
  >
  > c. 1300, repenten, "be grieved over one's past and seek forgiveness; feel such regret for sins, crimes, or omissions as produces amendment of life," from Old French repentir (11c.), from re-, here perhaps used as an intensive prefix, "very much" (see re-), + Vulgar Latin *penitire "to regret," from Latin poenitire "make sorry," from poena (see penal).

  > repentance (n.)
  >
  > c. 1300, repentaunce, "state of being penitent, sorrow and contrition for sin or wrongdoing resulting in vigorous abandonment of it in one's life," from Old French repentance "penitence" (12c.), from present-participle stem of repentir (see repent).

From etymology online, is it correct that penance and penitence share Latin paenitentia as their most recent ancestor?

Is repent / repentance isolated from the other two groups? What is the most recent ancestor between it and the other two groups?

For penitence, does "from Old French penitence (11c.) and directly from Latin pænitentia" mean that Old French penitence is derived from Latin pænitentia, or Old French penitence  and directly  Latin pænitentia don't have derivative relationship between them?

Comment: This might be beyond the scope of the English Language Learners site - it seems more like an ELU or Linguistics SE question.